# React auto add/remove fields based on useState. HTML does not reflect the state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, use-state

I am using useState to create an array of objects that later are used to return form fields. User should be able to click on a button and remove a form field based on index.
For that I am using spread operator to get a shallow copy of the array, splice delete array item and update form fields through useState.

The problem is that when you click on delete button only last field is removed without regards of the index. Consoling array storing info for the form fields shows that it is updated properly but html is not reflecting the change.

code fragment:

```
const SearchPage = () => {
  let [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [results, setResults] = useState()
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState()
  const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState([
    { url: ''}
  ])


  const handleFormChange = (event, index) => {
    let data = [...formFields];
    data[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setFormFields(data);
  }


  const addFields = () => {
    let object = {
      url: '',
    }
    console.log('Before:',formFields)
    setFormFields([...formFields, object])
  }

  const removeFields = (index) => {
    let data = [...formFields];
    
    data.splice(index, 1)
    console.log(data)
    setFormFields(data)
  }

  return (
            <Box  noValidate autoComplete="off" >
                

              <div className='search' > 
                  <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                  {formFields.map((form, index) => {
                    console.log(form)

                    return (
                      <div key={index} style={{width: '95%'}}>
                        <TextField id="outlined-basic"
                          name='url'
                          onChange={event => handleFormChange(event, index)}
                          value={form.name}
                        />
                        <IconButton onClick={() => removeFields(index)}><DeleteIcon /></IconButton>
                      </div>
                    )
                  })}
                </form>
                <IconButton onClick={addFields}> <AddCircleOutlineOutlinedIcon /> </IconButton>
                <br />
              </div>
              </Box>

)
```

Comment: Another thing: You should spread the updated object just like the array (in `handleFormChange`): `data[index] = { ...data[index], [event.target.name]: event.target.value}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are assigning value form.name to textfield value which does not exist..

```
                  <TextField id="outlined-basic"
                          name='url'
                          onChange={event => handleFormChange(event, index)}
                          // form.url will fix your issue
                          value={form.url}
                        />
```

Comment: oh, right!! it works now and i prefer this way because it keeps my form state cleaner (w/o key info). it's weird that React did not prompted any error. it was like: "sure buddy, i will grab it for you no time, lol"

Answer (score 2):

The reason is for the `key` prop you are setting for each `Textfield`. it has to be unique for each item.

```js
  const addFields = () => {
    let object = {
      key: Math.random(),
      url: '',
    }
    setFormFields([...formFields, object])
  }
```

```html
 <div key={form.key} style={{width: '95%'}}>
```

Comment: thanks! setting purely random index works but i though just a simple int (array index should be enough too)